# Can I use the Spotify Web API in Xcode to develop a native iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, spotify, spotify-app

I would like to use Swift and web languages to write my app but I'm confused as to how I can achieve this. Spotify's API is written in Obj C but I'd like to circumvent that as much as possible by using Obj C to stream songs and their web api to search and do other things.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I combine a iOS framework and Web API to make a iOS native app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664895/can-i-combine-a-ios-framework-and-web-api-to-make-a-ios-native-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bridging header to use Spotify's API in Swift. Create a new header file, add `#import "Spotify/Spotify.h"`, go to Build Settings and search for Objective-C Bridging Header (under Swift Compiler - Code Generation), and add the name of the header file you just made. You may also need to add "-all_load" under Other Linker Flags in Build Settings as well.